# Issue with fancybox Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I make one script to automaticaly include the images, it works well but the fancybox is not working.

```
<div style="width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto" id="fotos">

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        var cont = 1

        while(cont < 879){
            var stroke = "<a class='fancybox' rel='gallery1' href='fotos/big/festa_"+ cont +".jpg' title='Festa Vegas'><img src='fotos/festa_"+ cont +".jpg' alt='' /></a>"

            $("#fotos").append(stroke);
            cont++
        }
    });
    </script>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fotos").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fire on every image then you'll need to use the image class in fancybox. i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

There is no class of `.photos` in the code you have provided. should this have been on the individual image?

Rather then inject every image one at a time, do them all in one go:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var cont = 1,
        images = '';

    while(cont < 879){
        images += "<a class='fancybox' rel='gallery1' href='fotos/big/festa_"+ cont +".jpg' title='Festa Vegas'><img src='fotos/festa_"+ cont +".jpg' alt='' /></a>"
        cont++
    }
    $("#fotos").append(images);
});
```

This will improve the loading times

Comment: when i click on image, dont get the effect of "image in center and background black"

Comment: have you included fancybox's css file?

Comment: here's a print [Image][1]


  [1]: http://sistemas.vilavelha.com.br/newsletter/ricardo/print.png

Comment: and the css file is working correctly? no 404 in network tab or errors in your dev console

Comment: does the fancybox overlay have the correct id's? i.e. #fancybox-content if so what styles are being applied to the id?

Comment: I believe yes, when i click the "active" image get into some fancybox divs and get position, overflow, etc...

Comment: But the image not get into the effect and just move the photo position and remove it from page.

Here's a link to the website.[Site][1]


  [1]: http://sistemas.vilavelha.com.br/newsletter/ricardo/festa_ano_novo_2014/index.asp

Comment: Yep, you css isnt loading, might be the number of divs you are creating, change  while(cont < 879){ to  while(cont < 5){ then check your network tab. the css file isnt loading for me

Comment: change to 5, stil not working, and the script are not creating divs, just add <a><img> (the basic structure for fancy).

Comment: i change to ".fancybox", to "#photos", "#photos img", nothing works, every stance works getting the image in center, but no one gets the image with black background

Comment: update answer. you are injecting every image individually. this might help. The issue you are seeing is because the css isnt loading

Comment: Ok, i put the css directly in the index.asp and works, just dont know why its not getting the css.